# Preserve Timestamp Column during Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a sizeable pandas df that I would like to aggregate by a Timestamp. The timestamps are on a granular scale(one second). Post aggregation, I would like the df to retain the first instance of that timestamp, but aggragated the following data by one minute periods.

```
Original:
Timestamp          Column
22-02-23 9:30:00   1
22-02-23 9:30:01   4
...
22-02-23 9:33:04   4
22-02-23 9:33:05   7
```

```
Grouped:
Timestamp          Column
22-02-23 9:30:00   5
...
22-02-23 9:33:04   11
```

Is there a pandas function for this? Or does this aggregation need to be done manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
df["Hour_Minute"] = df["Timestamp"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
df.groupby("Hour_Minute").first()
```